# Como usar a função rm sem apagar tudo, deixando apenas um ou dois vetores?

Tags: r

Não quero excluir `vec1` e `a` do meu workspace. Eu tentei

```
vec1 <- c(1,2,3)    
vec2 <- c(2,3)    
a <- 2    
b <- 3    
x <- vec1    
y <- a    
   
cleanmem <- function(x,y){    
  mem = vector()    
  mem <- ls(all.names = T)    
  mem <- mem[which(mem != "x" & mem != "y" )]    
  rm(list=(mem));gc()
}    
cleanmem(x,y);ls()
```

ou

```
cleanmem <- function(x,y){
list = ls(all.names = T)
list <- list[which(list != "x" & list != "y" )]
rm(list)
gc()
}
cleanmem(x,y)
ls()
```

Também tentei

```
cleanmem <- function(x,y){
    rm(list = ls()[which(list != "x" & list != "y" )])
    gc()
}
cleanmem(x,y)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela edição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema são os ambientes. Cada função em R cria uma ambiente para si e tanto `ls` quanto `rm` atuam por default no ambiente atual.

Para afetar o ambiente global você tem que especificá-lo diretamente. Para isso você pode adicionar um parâmetro ambiente ao código. Fiz a mudança no primeiro exemplo com uma função recebendo strings e uma recebendo argumentos com `...`.
Obs: lembre-se que dessa maneira a própria função também é apagada. Todos os objetos no global environment são apagados, inclusive outras funções que você criou antes no código.

```r
vec1 <- c(1,2,3)    
vec2 <- c(2,3)    
a <- 2    
b <- 3    

environment()
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

test_function <- function() print(environment())

test_function()
#> <environment: 0x2571008>

cleanmem_general <- function(to_keep = c(), target_env = .GlobalEnv){    
  all_vars <- ls(all.names = T, envir = target_env)    
  to_remove <- all_vars[which(!(all_vars %in% to_keep))]    
  rm(list = to_remove, pos = target_env);gc()
}    

cleanmem_general(c("vec1", "a"));ls()
#>          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#> Ncells 486124 26.0    1050760 56.2   676331 36.2
#> Vcells 894859  6.9    8388608 64.0  1820804 13.9
#> [1] "a"    "vec1"

vec1 <- c(1,2,3)    
vec2 <- c(2,3)    
a <- 2    
b <- 3    

cleanmem_nse <- function(..., target_env = .GlobalEnv){
  to_keep <- as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1]
  all_vars <- ls(all.names = T, envir = target_env)    
  to_remove <- all_vars[which(!(all_vars %in% to_keep))]    
  rm(list = to_remove, pos = target_env);gc()
}    

cleanmem_nse(vec1, a);ls()
#>          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#> Ncells 486215 26.0    1050760 56.2   676331 36.2
#> Vcells 894943  6.9    8388608 64.0  1820804 13.9
#> [1] "a"    "vec1"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Que blz Jorge Mendes, muito obrigado. Mas teríamos como declarar vec1 e a dentro de cleanmem_modificada(x,y). Nesse caso resolvido é preciso fazer antes da função x <- vec1. E ao passar por cleanmem_modificada(x,y), chamar vec1 <-  x. Já resolve, mas teríamos como já deixar mais otimizado?

Comment: Entendi, eu só tinha me atentado ao problema principal de ambientes. Vou fazer uma modificação com isso.

Comment: Só consegui atualizar agora @FabianoBrião. mas tá aí algo mais geral

Comment: Então, eu me liguei nisso, que a função seria apagada. Acho que vou investir num cartão de memória maior mesmo. kkkk, Estou entrando na área de Data Science, sou professor de matemática em IES a 10 anos e agora a coisa ficou muito preta. Daí, como já fazia alguns trabalhos com R quando alguém próximo pedia, vou me aprofundar até o final do ano, mas vou migrar para o Python, que acho tem bem mais oportunidades). Eu já sou matemático/estatístico de profissão, vamos ver como fica a vida agora mudando de área. Obrigado, abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Para remover todos menos um objeto:

```
rm(list = ls()[-a])
```

Para remover todos menos alguns objetos:

```
rm(list=ls()[!ls() %in% c("a", "b")])

# ou

rm(list = setdiff(ls(), c("a", "b")))
```